# Reorganizing a 2d array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

The comment in the code is what I'm trying to get it to do, change the array from "12345, 12345, 12345 to 111,222,333,444,555"

```
 public void reorganize()
{

     for(int y = 0; y < repeat; y++)//this loop reorganizes the arrays. Each array is now organized by number location rather than how it was inputted. Ex: 12345, 12345, 12345 is now 111,222,333,444,555
   {
        for(int r = 0; y==4; r++)
        {
        newNumbers[r][y] = numbers[y][r];   
        }            
    }
```

I've been trying to fix this and I've rewritten it a couple times but it never ends up working right. This is my first time posting on SO and I hope you guys can help me (:

Thank you

Comment: Please give us the full code. Where and how is newNumbers initialized?

Comment: A) Post an MVCE. Otherwise it's just guesswork. What is `repeat`? What are the dimensions of `numbers`? B) Post the *specific problem*. You posted what you want, and your code. Is it an exception you encountered? Wrong output? Compilation issue? C) Why do you terminate on `y==4` and not `r == 4` in the inner for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you start by passing in the `numbers` array and returning your `newNumbers` array. Basically, your logic should rotate the dimensions of the input `numbers` array to construct `newNumbers`, but then your copy logic is correct (once you fix the loop test conditions).

```
public static int[][] reorganize(int[][] numbers) {
    int[][] newNumbers = new int[numbers[0].length][numbers.length];
    for (int y = 0; y < numbers.length; y++) {
        for (int r = 0; r < numbers[y].length; r++) {
            newNumbers[r][y] = numbers[y][r];
        }
    }
    return newNumbers;
}
```

Then you should be able to test it like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] numbers = { { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 },
            { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 } };
    int[][] newNumbers = reorganize(numbers);
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(newNumbers));
}
```

Output is (as requested)

```
[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4], [5, 5, 5]]
```

Comment: Thank you! I used your double nested loop and that simple fix fixed my whole program and now it's working!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
    Integer[][] numbers = new Integer[5][3];
    // Fill numbers
    Integer[][] newNumbers = new Integer[3][5];

    for(int y = 0; y < numbers.length; y++)//this loop reorganizes the arrays. Each array is now organized by number location rather than how it was inputted. Ex: 12345, 12345, 12345 is now 111,222,333,444,555
    {
        for(int r = 0; r < numbers[0].length; r++)
        {
            newNumbers[r][y] = numbers[y][r];
        }
    }
```